# Removing parameters from URL when using Url view helper links

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

When using the Url view helper to build links, if the current page has parameters in the url, the url generated by the Url view helper will contains parameters as well.

For instance in the page **/controller/action/param/value/** the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index'
)) ?>">Dashboard</a>
```

will output:

```
<a href="/index/index/param/value/">Dashboard</a>
```

Is it possible to clean the url outputted by the helper of parameters?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the third parameter to the helper will clear the default params, e.g.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index'
), null, true) ?>">Dashboard</a>
```

Documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial

Comment: Are you following me Karim? :)

Comment: what do the null and true values stand for?

Comment: See http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_Url.html - the third parameter is whether or not to reset route defaults with those provided, and the fourth whether to encode the url