# Zend Framework GET parameter still there after change page

Tags: zend-framework, url, redirect, parameters, get

I don't get if is a normal behavior of the Zend Framework or something is wrong...

For example...   If I click to a link like this:

```
        <a href="<?= $this->url(array(
                                 'controller' => 'SubCategory',
                                 'action' => 'index',
                                 'Category__ID' => 4)); ?>">
        </a>
```

So the URL ( where it will redirect ) will be:  www.mydomain.com/SubCategory/index/Category__ID/4

Does correct...

But now that I'm in the page with this URL:   www.mydomain.com/SubCategory/index/Category__ID/4

I click a link like that:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array(
                         'controller' => 'Index',
                         'action' => 'index')); ?>">Home</a>
```

It will go to the URL:  www.mydomain.com/Index/index/Category__ID/4

But why?

Should not be just:   www.mydomain.com/Index/index     ????

Why he still have the GET parameter?

**Is it a normal behavior or something is wrong in my application?   And if something is wrong, what can be?**

Thanks again...

Samuele

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing parameters from URL when using Url view helper links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993725/removing-parameters-from-url-when-using-url-view-helper-links)

Comment: It's a normal behavour and your question is a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry...  I tried to search for at least 20 minutes but I didn't found the answer...  Thanks anyway...  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. After the array with the parameter of the url write this: NULL, TRUE like that

```
$this->url(array(...), NULL, TRUE);
```

The True means that the url will be absolute and not relative.