# Zend view url function issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

first I'd like to admit I didn't do enough searching about this mainly because I didn't know how to put it in words fit for the search. is it 'getting clean urls in zend' or 'ignore what comes after the action in zend' I really can't name it well, so deeply sorry for this. guide me for duplicates, I'll delete this at once :>

now, story goes like this:
let's say in page`project/public/home` I've got a link

```
<a href="<?php  
echo $this->url(array(
            'controller' => 'test',
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
        ?>
           ">
               <?php echo $this->translate('go_to_test_index'); ?>
</a>
```

that would get me to `project/public/home/test/index` (index omitted by default)

let's say another link with parameter

```
<a href="<?php
        echo $this->url(array(
            'controller' => 'message',
            'action' => 'add',
            'id' => 1//some value or another parameter
        ));
        ?>
           ">
               <?php echo $this->translate('go_to_add_message'); ?>
</a>
```

that would take me to `project/public/home/message/add/1` till now I understand perfectly but the issue appears when I try to go back

```
<a href="<?php
        echo $this->url(array(
            'controller' => 'test',
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
        ?>
           ">
               <?php echo $this->translate('back'); ?>
</a>
```

as far as I know that should take me to `project/public/home/test/index` but instead I get `project/public/home/test/index/id/1` (index not omitted) the test/index page is displayed but that id parameter is just wrong to be there

what is the proper name of this problem? what's causing it? am I missing some parameter of `url`? any pointers on how to fix it?

thanks a lot in advance

**duplicate of** [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993725/removing-parameters-from-url-when-using-url-view-helper-links)

documentation referenced there [Zend View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reset option in the Url View Helper as shown below.

```
<a href="<?php
        echo $this->url(array(
            'controller' => 'test',
            'action' => 'index'
        ), null, true);
        ?>
           ">
               <?php echo $this->translate('back'); ?>
</a>
```

And here are few more tips for generating Urls.

1. Create a virtual host and point it to your projects public directory.
2. Use BaseUrl helper to generate absolute Urls.
3. Create routes and generate Urls using routes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I knew there's gotta be a switch off somewhere! thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

As @Jay Bhatt mentioned, there is a `reset` param which is defaulted to false.

Set it to `true` if you want to reset all current request params in the new generated link.

```
<a href="<?php 
    echo $this->url(
        array('controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index'), 
        null, 
        true
    );
        ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('back'); ?></a>
```

Note that if you want to reset only one param, you can set it as `null`

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
    'controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => null
));
    ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('back'); ?></a>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: aha~ even more control over resetting with one-param access! thanks a lot